# Why does a Java Tensorflow session seem to reset state when a Python Tensorflow session does not?

Tags: java, python, tensorflow

I am trying to build and evaluate TensorFlow Graphs via the 1.4 Java API, on Linux. I have noticed that the Java API seems to reset the value of operation output tensors each time a call to Session.run() is made. This behavior does not seem to match what happens in Python. My eventual question (see below for details) is how to avoid this apparent behavior?

## Python Example

By way of example here is Python code (also using the 1.4 API) that increments the value in a Scalar Tensor.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> x = tf.get_variable("x", [], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
>>> step = tf.constant(1.0)
>>> xUpdateOp = x.assign_add(step)
>>> s = tf.Session()
>>> s.run(x.initializer)
>>> x.eval(s)
0.0
>>> s.run(xUpdateOp)
1.0
>>> x.eval(s)
1.0
>>> s.run(xUpdateOp)
2.0
>>> x.eval(s)
2.0
>>>
```

Notice that as expected, evaluating x gives its current value, and using the session to run the xUpdateOp causes x to get larger by 1.

## Java Example

This is my attempt to use Java to build a Tensorflow graph that increments a Scalar Tensor. Initialization is different in the Java API because it lacks some of Pythons convenience methods.

```
public static void doCounting(){
    try(Graph g = new Graph()){
        try(Tensor<Float> zeroT = Tensors.create(0.0f);
            Tensor<Float> stepT = Tensors.create(1.0f)){
            Output<Float> zero = g.opBuilder("Const", "start")
                    .setAttr("dtype", zeroT.dataType())
                    .setAttr("value", zeroT)
                    .build().output(0);
            Output<Float> step = g.opBuilder("Const", "step")
                    .setAttr("dtype", stepT.dataType())
                    .setAttr("value", stepT)
                    .build().output(0);
            Output<Float> xVar = g.opBuilder("Variable", "x")
                    .setAttr("dtype", zero.dataType())
                    .setAttr("shape", zero.shape())
                    .build().output(0);
            Output<Float> x = g.opBuilder("Assign", "init_x")
                    .addInput(xVar)
                    .addInput(zero)
                    .build().output(0);

            Operation xUpdateOp = g.opBuilder("AssignAdd", "x_get_x_plus_step")
                    .addInput(x)
                    .addInput(step)
                    .build();

            try(Session s = new Session(g)) {
                s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();
                s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();
                s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();

                try(Tensor<Float> result = s.runner().fetch(xUpdateOp.name(), 0).run().get(0).expect(Float.class)){
                    System.out.println(result.floatValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above code snip

```
1.0
```

But I expected it to be 4.0 because I called run() on xUpdateOp 4 times. Even if I am off-by-one 1.0 is not what I expected.

## Question

What do I need to do with this Java example to get the same behavior as the Python example? How do I get the xUpdateOp to use the value of x calculated in a previous call to run()?

### What I have already tried

I have already tried to use the feed() function to feed in an x value

```
try(Session s = new Session(g)) {
    try(Tensor<Float> x1 = s.runner().fetch(xUpdateOp.name()).run().get(0).expect(Float.class)) {
        s.runner().feed(xUpdateOp.name(), 0, x1);
        try (Tensor<Float> result = s.runner().fetch(xUpdateOp.name(), 0).run().get(0).expect(Float.class)) {
            System.out.println(result.floatValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
1.0
```

I have also tried to call run() without an addTarget or a fetch(), thinking that the addTarget or fetch() is what is causing the state to be reset. Perhaps once a session understands what to run, it can run it several times.

```
try(Session s = new Session(g)) {
    s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();
    s.runner().run();
    s.runner().run();

    try(Tensor<Float> result = s.runner().fetch(xUpdateOp.name(), 0).run().get(0).expect(Float.class)){
        System.out.println(result.floatValue());
    }
}
```

Result

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify at least one target to fetch or execute.
at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:298)
at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:248)
at org.tensorflow.examples.Example.doCounting(MandelbrotExample.java:80)
at org.tensorflow.examples.Example.main(MandelbrotExample.java:50)
ERROR: Non-zero return code '1' from command: Process exited with status 1.
```

### Somewhat related questions

[How to create/initialize a Variable with Tensorflow 1.0 Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813989/how-to-create-initialize-a-variable-with-tensorflow-1-0-java-api)

[java tensorflow reset_default_graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565238/java-tensorflow-reset-default-graph)

[Java - train loaded tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605690/java-train-loaded-tensorflow-model)

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Perhaps the difference really is in the initialization. Is Tensorflow rerunning the "init_x" operation at each call to s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, `xUpdateOp` has `x` as its input, and `x` is the output of the operation that assigns `zero` to the variable. Thus, every time `xUpdateOp` is run, it is first assigning zero to the variable.

A slight tweak to your code will result in 4.0:

```
# Changed addInput(x) to addInput(xVar)
Operation xUpdateOp =
    g.opBuilder("AssignAdd", "x_get_x_plus_step").addInput(xVar).addInput(step).build();

try (Session s = new Session(g)) {
  # Initialize the variable once
  s.runner().addTarget(x.op()).run();
  s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();
  s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();
  s.runner().addTarget(xUpdateOp).run();

  try (Tensor<Float> result =
       s.runner().fetch(xUpdateOp.name(), 0).run().get(0).expect(Float.class)) {
    System.out.println(result.floatValue());
  }                     
}
```

Drawing a parallel with the Python code: The Java code snippet above is more like the Python code in the question. While the Java code in the question is more like the following in Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf

zero = tf.constant(0.0)
step = tf.constant(1.0)
xVar = tf.Variable(initial_value=zero, name="x")
x = tf.assign(xVar, zero)
xUpdateOp = tf.assign_add(x, step)
```

So `tf.assign_add(x, step)` vs `tf.assign_add(xVar, step)` would make all the difference. In the former, the `AssignAdd` operation applies on the output of the `Assign` operation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can confirm that this does fix the problem, but I don't understand why. The documentation for [AssignAdd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/assign-add), and its related operation "Assign" says "Output: = Same as "ref". Returned as a convenience for operations that want to use the new value after the variable has been updated." I read this to mean the returned value from the "Assign" that is acting as the initializer, was the initialized input variable, and could be used elsewhere as the variable.

Comment: I've attempted to explain by elaborating in the answer. Does that help?

Comment: The addition of the contrast between the Java and Python in your answer does help. The problem was in the use later in the graph of the result of the Tensorflow operation that initializes the variable, rather than the variable itself. It seems the return value from the "Assign" operator is the new value, not the variable populated with the new value. Thanks!